# Join columns names with values of given column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have `df_1` and `df_2` below. I am trying to figure out a way to replace the column names of `df_1` based on values in column `E` in `df_2`. Column `C` in `df_2` defines how they are related.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0, 1, 1],
    'B': [0, 1, 1],
    'rkgjh': [0, 1, 1],
    'hvdfe': [0, 1, 1],
    'qruif': [0, 1, 1]
})

df_1
    A   B   rkgjh   hvdfe   qruif
0   0   0   0       0       0
1   1   1   1       1       1
2   1   1   1       1       1

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'C': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'D': ['hvdfe', 'qruif', 'cvbnf', 'ertyu', 'rkgjh'],
    'E': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
})

df_2
    C   D       E
0   0   hvdfe   name1
1   1   qruif   name2
2   2   cvbnf   name3
3   3   ertyu   name4
4   4   rkgjh   name5
```

I would like to end up with `df_3` below:

```
df_3
    A   B   name5   name1   name2
0   0   0       0   0       0
1   1   1       1   1       1
2   1   1       1   1       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.replace`:

```
df_3 = df_1.copy()
df_3.columns=df_1.columns.to_series().replace(df_2.set_index('D')['E'])
```

Output:

```
   A  B  name5  name1  name2
0  0  0      0      0      0
1  1  1      1      1      1
2  1  1      1      1      1
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this behave like an `inner join`? So that if there is no mapping for one of the columns in `df_1`, that column will be dropped.

Comment: so you want to drop `A` and `B`? If so, you can use `map` instead of `replace` and then `dropna` of some sort.

Comment: Does `dropna()` apply to column names?

Comment: No, but something like `df_3[df3.columns.drop_na()]`?